LEDs Progressively dimming even for light intermittent usage
We have been developing an LED array board with a PCA9959HNMP constant current driver, which controls SM0603UV-405 LEDs from Bivar.
The UV LED's absolute max forward current is 25 mA, I have used a 2.7 kΩ current limiting resistor to limit the current to 23 mA.
But I noticed the LEDs were prematurely dieng even with less than an hour of usage for 2 days. So I referred to the datasheet, the driver has a ±6.5 % absolute accuracy for 30 mA output current. Accounting for the worst-case scenario I lowered the current to Max 20 mA by modifying the code. The max brightness value being written to the register is 54 now.
But even after this modification, the LEDs are deteriorating for moderate usage. The LED VF stays the same even when I let it run for 2 days straight but the LEDs are dimmer than what they used to be.
Please provide any solutions or suggestions.

Low exposure Pic where one LED was replaced with new one
Updates - I monitored the VF and IF while letting the LED run continuously, the VF stayed at 3.2V and the IF was 20.2mA. There is no drift or signs of thermal shutdown. Both the LEDs and IC are marginally warm, I'll update the temperature values shortly. Also, I'm attaching the Histogram. We have a microscope setup with a camera attached to an objective lens, I have been saving the histogram for 4 days while LEDs were ruining continuously. The histogram shows that the grayscale intensity shows a decreasing trend. I have also attached the Pictures of the new and old LED for comparison. The new LEDs are cloudy but the old ones show the one junction has a brown tint and the package is clear.


The oscilloscope measurement is with respect to GND, not VF i.e across the diode. The anode of the diode is 4.8V always with respect to ground.

Update 2 - It seems the LEDs worsen faster with the driver compared to the bench top supply that is current limited, but it grows dimmer at a slower rate.


25mA is the "absolute maximum forward current", these LEDs should typically be drive with no more than 20mA (the "recommended forward current"). What sort of board area do you have these twenty-four LEDs on, and what are you doing about cooling? This is a total of ~1.6W for all 24x at 20mA, what temperature do the LEDs get to? If you're exceeding the 80°C rating, then their lifespan will be reduced. Note also that the PCA9959 seems to have an output accuracy of ~8%, so 20mA could be as much as 21.6mA - have you measured it?

The current was limited to 20mA by changing the code, I considered +-6.5% since the datasheet mentions that accuracy for LED current under 30mA. Also, there are only 12 of these LEDs that would be turned ON simultaneously, the other 12 are different LEDs from Kingbright that would be off when these LEDs are turned on.

As for measurement I have measured only the VF of one LED over 3 days it hasn't changed at all but the LEDs have grown dimmer with each passing day. I have attached the Board images for your reference, these are 0603 LEDs not much I can do for thermal dissipation and the LEDs are mildly warm if left at the max brightness.

Could it be that the PCA9959 goes into thermal shutdown? Chapter 9.1 of the datasheet mentions that. Running your LEDs from 5V at 20mA the LED Vf is typically 3.4V. This leaves the IC to drop 1.6V. That's 320mW per LED that the PCA9959 has to dissipate. Multiplied by 12, that's 3.84W which is a lot of power on such a small package. How is the Thermal pad designed? I don't see thermal VIAs to get the heat to the other side of the board...

The source voltage is 4.8V because of the ORing diode in a different PCB that supplies to this PCB. So (4.8-3.2 )V = (1.6V20mA) = (32mW12leds)  = 384mW for 12 LEDs.
The IC package is not warm either.

"not much I can do for thermal dissipation"  aluminum or copper core PCB comes to mind.

Did you get the LEDs from a reliable source? If not, I wouldn't be surprised if they're not upto spec. It isn't uncommon to derate LEDs to improve their lifetime, and the 'manufacturer' may have assumed noone will notice a slightly  lower spec

"aluminum or copper core PCB comes to mind" - I meant, for now, I know I can add a heatsink to the IC or do design changes to expose those thermal vias or go for a different substrate. But from my observations, the IC is not even warm to the touch.

"Did you get the LEDs from a reliable source?" - All the components have been sourced through Digikey. I haven't heard from Bivar either, I requested max operation hours but no reply yet.

That old LED turning brown is a sign of either straight up overheating or junk LED. Even Luxeon K2 back in the day had phosphor which couldn’t take the rated load and turned brown but I haven’t seen this on modern 2024 LEDs.

I suggest that you perform a series of measurements to figure out where the issue is.
I would start by asking myself if the issue is related to the LED or the drivers.
I would add a small resistor in series to one of the LED to create a resistive shunt to monitor the current through the LED. 0.47 Ohm or so.
The current should remain constant if your driver is a constant current driver. If the current is the same at the start of the experiment and 3 days later, then you can confidently remove "a drift of the driver" or "thermal shutdown" from the root cause of the issue. Next I would check what happens when the driver is enabled. Is it possible for it to set a current way above the LED limit for a short period? Is the limiting system working?
Next, I would ask myself if the LEDs are able to sustain that current for a long time in the actual environmental conditions. Here the datasheet is your friend.
Thermal effects are the next things on my list.

One can see on the datasheet that there is some thermal derating above 25°C.
That datasheet is pretty light on thermal characteristics of the LEDs. With such a lack of information, one can't accurately model the behavior of the LEDs. But according to the datasheet and the derating curve, I would definitely not put more that 20mA through that LED. And to be on the safe side, I would limit myself to something like 18mA or less.
Last but not least, how do you measure the optical output power of the LEDs?
These are UV LEDs: The main radiation lobe is at 405nm which is at the extreme edge of the human vision spectrum and almost invisible. What we see is the tail of the LED towards the red or any fluorescence of plastics, glue etc. The fluorescence may become dimmer when the plastic/glue material is degraded by the UV radiations. But this doesn't mean the 405nm radiation of interest is becoming weaker... Use a UV sensitive photodiode to monitor the UV power. Maybe it remains stable, and this is a non-issue.

Right or wrong, good spot that it may be fluorescence diminishing over time, and not necessarily the UV.

I have updated the post, Please have a look.

My experience with UV LEDs is to run them at 10% rated current and with good heat sinking to get usable life time. Not with those particular LEDs, but with others from reliable sources. If someone asked me to make a very long life device that should last 50k hours or longer, I’d run them at 1% of rated current. Yes it costs money but you get what you pay for.
At the moment, UV LED life is just very expensive compared to other LEDs. That’s why your experience may seem somewhat unusual if all you got to go on is other LEDs. This is how red LEDs were in their infancy. The spec current limit was not thermal but purely from measured life time. If it was a 1000hr LED, they’d figure out what current to run it at to get that life and that went into spec. The LED chip could work at a higher current, it would not overheat. It just lasted so much shorter, even when extensively cooled.
You should run both the IC and the LEDs at most warm to touch for longevity. More so for the LEDs than the IC. You seem to be doing that, so that’s great.
Now I’m not discounting off hand that what you experience with those particular LEDs is not up to their manufacturer’s spec. It may well be so. That’s why contacting the manufacturer is important.
You also need to do a wide bandwidth (1MHz at least) measurement of the current in the LED string. If the peak current is more than 120% of the average conservatively speaking, the life will suffer relative to the life at pure DC current.
Finally, if you’re not doing the measurements using a calibrated optical power meter with a narrowband filter, you are basically in the dark. I would not trust the results you have shown with the imaging setup. The gold standard is a wideband optical power meter and a selective filter to admit the rated UV emission wavelength range. The manufacturer will probably not want to bother until you show them hard data. I wouldn’t probably either. What you have is preliminary results that prompt further measurements using proper metrology :)
If you want to be double-sure, send your test boards to a lab that does optical power measurements. You will get dependable results well worth their price.

Thanks for the Insight, I did reach out to Bivar the LED manufacturer. Their engineering team suggested the Benchtop supply experiment. Also, I did do a shunt monitor with an ADC, but I haven't noticed any spike. This is a Linear dimming method without any Inductive elements can you explain why you would need a 1 MHZ measurement in this case?
